Conception of earth's size based on the width of the observable horizon when standing at sea level and the circumference of the earth
As an aid to conceiving of the size of the earth, using the information that the horizontal (left to right or right to left) width of (not the distance to) the observable horizon when standing at sea level is approximately 3.1 miles (5 kilometers) and the circumference is 24,901 miles (40,075 kilometers), can it be said that there are roughly slightly over 8,000 such horizons that fit into the circumference of the earth? I’m not sure if my colloquial, linear or arc notion of the observable horizon standing at a relatively “linear” beach is as correct a definition as one in which one pans one’s head 360 degrees. Actually, based on the distance to a lighthouse about 3 miles away on one side, the 3.1 mile distance for the observable width of the horizon seems a bit low -- by about half. (I got that 3.1 mile number off the internet). Perhaps there may be some perspective diminishment at play somehow.
I note the answer to a previously deleted, related question was:
If we are on a beach, and our eyes at 3m above the sea level, the horizon is a circle of about 6km. It seems consistent with our intuition.



Actually, based on the distance to a lighthouse about $3 \  \text{miles}$ away on
one side, the $3.1 \ \text{mile}$ distance for the observable width of the
horizon seems a bit low -- by about half.

All beaches are sloped and if you are not standing exactly on the water's edge, you will see much further and that might explain what you are observing. If your shoes were dry after making the observation, you probably were not doing it right.

If we are on a beach, and our eyes at $3 \ \text{m}$ above the sea level, the
horizon is a circle of about $6 \ \text{km}$.
$$ r_n = \sqrt{R_e^2 - h^2} = \sqrt{(6371)^2 - (0.003)^2} = 6.2 \ \text{km} $$

The equation you quoted is not correct. If you enter it into a calculator with those numbers, the result is actually $6370.99 \ \text{km}$, which is obviously not the answer you are looking for.
Here is the derivation of the correct equation:

$\text{E}$ represents the location of your eyeballs and the dashed line is a tangent to the Earth's surface along your line of sight. $\text{EHA}$ is a right angled triangle with hypotenuse $\text{EA}$ equal to $(R_{\text{E}} + h)$ and sides $j = R_{\text{E}}$ and $u$, where $u$ is the distance from your eyeballs to the base of the lighthouse or whatever you are looking at, at the horizon. Using Pythagoras we get the relation:
$$u^2 + j^2 = (R_{\text{E}} + h)^2.$$
This solves to:
$$u = \sqrt{2 R_{\text{E}} h + h^2}.$$
which is the distance from your eyeballs to the horizon. I hope you will agree the distance from your feet to the horizon is not much different, although it might not look like that in the diagram because it is most definitely not to scale.
Putting numbers into the new equation we get:
$$u = \sqrt{2 \times 6371 \times 0.003 + 0.0003^2} = 6.18 \ \text{km},$$
or nearly $4 \ \text{miles}$.
I notice you are using $h = 3 \ \text{m}$ when the height of a typical person is nearer to $2 \ \text{m}$. If you are standing right on the waters edge and use $h = 2 \ \text{m}$, the distance to the horizon works out as nearer $5.04 \ \text{km}$.  Note this is the radius of the horizon circle. The diameter of the horizon circle is twice that, so somewhere between $10$ and $12 \ \text{km}$.

As an aid to conceiving of the size of the earth, using the
information that the horizontal (left to right or right to left) width
of (not the distance to) the observable horizon when standing at sea
level is approximately $3.1 \ \text{miles}$ ($5 \ \text{km}$) and the circumference
is $24,901 \ \text{miles}$ ($40,075 \  \text{km}$), can it be said that there are
roughly slightly over $8,000$ such horizons that fit into the
circumference of the Earth?

Using the $12 \ \text{km}$ figure for the diameter of the visible horizon we can say there are roughly $\dfrac{40,075}{12} = 3339$ such horizons that fit into the circumference of the Earth.
Note that the above derivation assumes the Earth is a perfect sphere when in reality it is more of an oblate spheroid. In practice I do not think this will make much difference to the calculations over the distances concerned.
It is also interesting to note that if the Earth was flat we could in principle see the sea-level base of a lighthouse, that was orders of magnitude further away than $6 \ \text{km}$, away using a telescope.
When on holiday, I have sometimes watched ships going out to sea and notice that eventually the hull of the ship disappears below the horizon and I can only see the tips of the ships masts and funnels. I often wonder how flat earthers explain those sort of observations.

Thanks very much for the answer. The equation makes sense and I'll continue to study its details. I note that I am panning my head from the waters edge at the beach, say about, 160 degrees to encompass the visible ocean horizon bordered by the shore.  If 160 degrees is 1.7 times larger than 90 degrees, would that mean that there are 5676 such horizons?

I think the radial distance to the visible horizon should remain constant whichever direction you look in. (Assuming the spherical Earth approximation).

One thing I find confusing is that the ocean from the water's edge seems to be about, say, a sixth or less of the horizon circle area were I to pan my head 360 degrees, even though I'm standing at a relatively "linear" beach. I find this hard to wrap my head around, since I'm expecting a line to divide the ocean from land exactly half.

My house is about 100m above sea level and I can I get a view of the sea. Oddly enough when I look out to sea the horizon looks straight to me rather than a semi circle. I am not sure why that is. It must be some sort of optical or mental illusion. I am sure if I was on a tower on a island in the middle of the ocean I would see the horizon as a complete circle. I think part of the solution is that we have a relatively narrow field of vision and we only see a small portion of the horizon at any time and we mentally stitch images together and to make a metal picture of a straight line.  ...

... If we had wrap-around vision like a rabbit, we would probably see the curve. If we we use a fish eye lens on a camera to capture a wide angle we can obtain a photograph with a curved horizon.

Perhaps try mounting binoculars or a camera on a tripod on the edge of the sea and pan it from one end of the beach to the opposite direction and get an an actual measurement of the angle you have to turn through. Also remember that most maps are a Mercator projection and the process of converting a spherical surface to a flat surface introduces some distortion. If your beach looks straight on a map it might actually be slightly curved. You would have to investigate this further and use actual satellite coordinates.

Thanks. I did use a (printable) protractor. I think that "mentally stitching images together" is certainly a good probability, judging by our experiences with illusions of all sorts. I wonder if panning one's head is in it self a circular motion, which could somehow factor in to our circular panning perception while looking at the curvature. I have seen (begrudgingly) that the curvature is indeed much flatter when in the water than even, say, half a foot up on land. This considerably significant difference, however, has me skeptical about perception, since the earth is so large.
